# Can anyone tell me why my alert(id) isn't firing off? Nada, zilch, zippo

Tags: javascript

First of all let me say thank you to everyone that offered answers...I have definitely advanced and even on my local machine everything is working perfectly.

However it's not working on the server. I tried a bunch of things such as putting session_start() into the included files but nothing has taken.

Rather than post the code here I've zipped up a few files:

http://nerotic.net/aux/code.zip

and you can see the site at the same URL removing /code.zip

index.php: has the AJAX in it...
index_page_content.inc.php: is my file to determine which content gets included
backend.php: the PHP to process the AJAX
sound-how.php: one of the pages that gets included by index.php

The behavior is weird. It won't echo 'src' where I echo it, however it will display it where I'm echoing 'section'. But as soon as I reload it goes back to echoing 'section' in the exact same place.

Also, in Chrome every couple of links that I click on makes the entire page reload.

So if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong :)

Thanks in advance.

> ORIGINAL POST

I'm new at PHP and relearning JS so any help would be appreciated.

```
<script language="JavaScript"
type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

          $("div.tabs").tabs(".images > div", {

                // enable "cross-fading" effect
                effect: 'fade',
                fadeInSpeed: 600,
                fadeOutSpeed: 1000,

                // start from the beginning after the last tab
                rotate: false

              // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own> configuration
              }).slideshow({autoplay: false, interval:5000});


          $("a.lnav").onclick(function() {
                    // Get the ID of the link
                    var src = $(this).attr("id");
                    alert(id);

                    // Send Ajax request to backend.php, with src set as "id in> the POST data
                    $.post("/backend.php", {"id": src});
                });

          });  </script>
```

Comment: Do you have the HTML that gets ouput from the PHP?

Comment: Sorry to pick on you, since this is a common thing with jQuery users, but `$(this).attr("id")` is insane. What's wrong with `this.id`?

Comment: @Tim Down:  It doesn't work in IE6?  :P  Kidding!

Comment: What do you use to debug JS? I used to ask this type of question all the time (to myself anyway) because I didn't know how to debug JS code in a browser. But in Firefox you can use the Error Console (`Ctrl+Shift+J`) or install the Firebug plugin and use its console--much more powerful. Then you'll know exactly why your script is failing. It makes spotting simple/minor mistakes like syntax errors much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've pasted your code exactly as you set it up you're calling an non-existent method in jQuery.  You mean to be using `$('a.lnav').click()`.

Comment: Thank you :)

I can't believe all the excellent help I've gotten in a short time.

Answer (score 7):

Isn't it just .click to bind the event not .onclick?

Comment: Good spot - would say this is it

Comment: Sounds like it...I'll give this a shot as well.

Answer (score 6):

you probably meant to do `alert(src);`, can't see any where in yout code where a variable `id` has a value assigned to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("a.lnav").click(function() {
                // Get the ID of the link
                var src = $(this).attr("id");
                alert(src);

                // Send Ajax request to backend.php, with src set as "id in> the POST data
                $.post("backend.php", {id: src});
            });
```

Comment: `onclick` should be changed to `click` , then you want to alert the src var. Then you have another error in the `$.post` it is not `{"id":src}` but `{id:src}`

Answer (score 1):

You don't define id for `alert(id);` - would that throw an error rather than an alert?

Is there an `<a>` tag with a class of `lnav` like `<a class="lnav">`?

Comment: Sorry, my 1st post here and my 1st day with AJAX and pretty new to PHP as well.

Here's a sample link:

<a href="index.php?page=soundwhy" id="soundwhy"  class="lnav">why</a>